# using ggplotly on a factoextra object

Tags: r, plotly, factominer

Consider following code:

```
  library(FactoMineR)
  library(dplyr)
  library(factoextra)
  library(plotly)
  pca1<-PCA(iris[,1:4])
  fpi<-fviz_pca_ind(pca1,habillage = iris$Species)
  fpi
```

[image]

Now when execute following code, the groups repeat twice as shown in picture. How to solve this?

```
  ggplotly(fpi)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use  `label = "var"`

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(dplyr)
library(factoextra)
library(plotly)
pca1<-PCA(iris[,1:4])

#Here use label = "var"
fpi<-fviz_pca_ind(pca1,habillage = iris$Species, label = "var")
fpi
ggplotly(fpi)
```